# What is this algebra called?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

After learning about [split-complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number) and [dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) as generalizations of the idea of [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number), I start wondering what if we define the symbol $x$ to be idempotent, i.e., $x^2=x$. Then the multiplication of two numbers gives

$$(a+bx)(c+dx)=ac+(ad+bc+bd)x.$$

If $x^2=-1$, we get complex numbers. If $x^2=1$, we get split-complex numbers. If $x^2=0$, we get dual numbers. A matrix representation of such numbers is given by

$$(a+bx)(c+dx)\leftrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\0 & a+b
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
c & d\\0 & c+d
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
ac & ad+bc+bd\\0 & (a+b)(c+d)
\end{pmatrix}\!.$$

What is this algebra called? There seems to be an endless number of possibilities in defining what $x^2$ would be. Where can I learn more about this topic?

Comment: You get two copies of R, same as with the split complex numbers. Up to isomorphism you have already listed all the possibilities. You can learn more in any textbook covering the Chinese remainder theorem for rings.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, So you mean $x^2=x$ is the same as $x^2=1$? That's not very obvious to me.

Comment: Given any $a,b\in\mathbb R$ you get an algebra $\mathbb R[x]/\langle x^2-ax-b\rangle$. But up to isomorphism, you essentially only get the three algebras, depending on whether $b^2-4ac$ is positive, negative, or zero.

Comment: If $x^2=1$, then $y=\frac12(1+x)$ satisfies $y^2=y$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I see. Defining $x^2=ax+b$ is like doing the polynomial algebra modulo $x^2-ax-b$. That's an interesting idea. Can you write an answer?

Comment: When talking about split complex number you should say that $j=x\ne \pm1$, and like wise when talking about dual numbers, $\varepsilon=x\ne0$. Just pointing it out

Comment: @Holo, yes. I now have a better understanding of why we insist that $x$ is only a symbol in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Comment: *What is this algebra called?* Algebras with names are rather exceptional.  While christening algebras this name or that name was popular during the 19th century, I think as ring theory came into its own everyone quickly realized that wasn't sustainable.  If pressed I'd only be able to come up with a list of maybe a dozen algebras which have characteristic names like that, and quite a few with not-very-unique names like "polynomial ring over $\mathbb R$", but other than that there aren't names  like "dual numbers" for this sort of thing.

Answer (score -1):

The equation $x^2=x$ (that is, $x^2-x=0$) has four solutions in split-complex numbers: $0$,$1$, $1/2+j/2$, $1/2-j/2$.

$\mathbb{R}^2$ is isomorphic to split-complex numbers and also has four such elements: $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$.

Improper element $\infty$ of $\overline{\mathbb R}$ also satisfies the first equation.

Comment: Why is the downvote?